# Generic way to create comparer for objects behind pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, compare, functor

I use data structures, and I sort these data structures a lot. These data structures are holding pointers to objects, not directly the objects themselves. Now I can write a simple comparison functor, or function, to tell the sort algorithm how to sort the pointers:

```
struct Object_ptr_comparer {
    bool operator()(const Object* first, const Object* second) {
        return *first < *second;
    }
};
```

And use for example `std::sort`:

```
Object_ptr_comparer comp;
std::sort(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), comp);
```

The only problem with this solution that I have to write extra pointer comparator functor for any type of class. Yes, I could use inheritance and polymorphism to write only the comparator of some root class, but I don't want to. Is there any other smart way to do this?

Comment: You should use `std::less` instead of `<`.

Comment: I define the < operator for my classes, that's why i wrote that.

@jrok You are absolutely right, i always forget to use templates. :S

Comment: @Pubby, as far as I can tell `std::less` only exists so you can specify `operator<` in a functor. Is there some reason to prefer it to `operator<` directly?

Comment: @MarkRansom: `operator<` is invalid for unrelated pointers, but `std::less` is valid.

Comment: Oops, i did not know that `std::less` falls back to `operator<`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what templates are for!

```
struct ptr_comparer {
    template<class Object>
    bool operator()(const Object* first, const Object* second) const {
        return std::less<Object>()(*first, *second);
    }
};

std::sort(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), ptr_comparer());
```

Since I've templated the operator rather than specializing the comparer directly, the compiler can deduce the types, so we don't have to put the types directly.

I use `std::less` rather than `operator<`, because it safely compares pointers to pointers (like `char**`), rather than relying on Undefined Behavior.  `std::less` falls back on `operator<`, so it doesn't add any complexity to calling code, and there should be no downside.

[I'm certain this one compiles](http://ideone.com/EZGyi6)

Comment: My compiler says that I'm missing template argument before '(' in the `operator()`. If I use this:  `std::less<Object> l; return l(*first, *second);` it works. :S

Comment: Your edit won't work either, i already tried. It seems to me you are calling the parametrized constructor: `no matching function for call to 'std::less<track>::less(const some_class&, const some_class&)'`.

Comment: You can use `return std::less<Object>()(*first, *second);`.

Comment: @WonderCsabo: Good catch, that's _twice in one post_ I forgot that `std::less` isn't a function >.<

Answer (score 10):

What about a template?

```
struct ptr_comparer {
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* first, const T* second) {
        return *first < *second;
    }
};
```

used like this:

```
std::sort(data_str.begin(), data_str.end(), ptr_comparer());
```

Comment: If you template the operator rather than the struct then T can be deduced.